# I' trying to change the color of all group horizontal bar in IONIC 3 with chart.js

Tags: typescript, ionic3, chart.js

Hello I am trying to change the color of a specific group of a horizontal bar, for example in the image the group 15 must have only one color, as well as the 14 and successively and the library alternates it, there is some way to change it or use another library to make that kind of change within a horizontal bar group, i'm using chart.js and ionic 3

```
public barChartData: any[] = [
{
  label: 'C1',
        data: [17, 23 , 78, 89, 75, 41, 65, 79],

    },
    {
        data: [82, 228 , 399, 395, 325, 220, 421, 432],
  label: 'C2'
    },
    {
        data: [59, 199, 299, 370, 315, 300, 321],
  label: 'C3'
    },
    {
        data: [94, 170 , 497, 440, 396, 490, 495, 400], 
  label: 'C4'
    }, ];
public barChartColors:Array<any> = [
{ 
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(24, 66, 128)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
},
{ 
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(134, 137, 142)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
},
{ 
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
},
{ 
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(225, 133, 36)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
},];

public barChartLabels: string[] = ['15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'];

<canvas baseChart height="310"
      [datasets]="barChartData"
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [colors]="barChartColors"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"
      [chartType]="barChartType"
      (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
      (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

[image: Image of App Ionic 3]

Comment: Please paste your chart rendering code with the post.

Comment: I edit the post and put the code.